# Android: Convert xml using xslt

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt

I want to transform some xml using an xsl-file and output the result somehow (I'm using Android Api Level 8).

My current activity looks like this, but the transformer stays null.
LogCat throws an `System.err` with `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException`, saying the xml is not well-formed, but I made sure it is.

I found a hint in LogCat that says `SystemId Unknown` just before the above error message.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class XsltTester extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = XsltTester.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {

            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.source));
            Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.products));

            TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
            OutputStream output = new StringOutputStream();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
            trans.transform(xmlSource, result);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the xml-file to be transformed (source.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- <?xml-stylesheet href="beatle.xsl" type="text/xsl"?> -->
<person>
 <name>
  <firstname>Paul</firstname>
  <lastname>McCartney</lastname>
 </name>
 <job>Singer</job>
 <gender>Male</gender>
</person>
```

And this is the corresponding xsl (products.xsl)

```
<xsl:template match="child::person">
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>
    <xsl:value-of select="descendant::firstname" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="descendant::lastname" />
   </title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <xsl:value-of select="descendant::firstname" />
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="descendant::lastname" />
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to practice your example for the benefit of my own project but I cannot instantiate or import StringOutputStream. Where is this class from? Have you written it yourself? I'm using API 8 as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what the problem is: I put the XML/XSLT files in res/xml not in res/raw with the result of mangled XML format.

Much ado about nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a lot of room for error in such a small piece of code. My guess is that the XML or XSL is to blame after all. There's probably a tiny typo in it. Can you attach the XML/XSLT as well?

Comment: I added the XML/XSLT. It's just a simple example transformation. I also found a hint in LogCat i also put the question.

Comment: The XSL is missing <xsl:stylesheet> at the top.

Comment: That's not the mistake, i just forgot to post. Sry :(