# Convert XML file using XSLT in Android

Tags: android, xml, xslt

I am new to Android.

I want to convert a XML file to HTML format using XSLT to display it in android.

Can you please tell me some tutorials or examples to follow?

I also tried the codes in the [Android: Convert xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4153560/778101)
But it didn't work. I am not sure what is "StringOutputStream" there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both your xml and xslt file in raw folder.
The generated html file will be stored in sdcard.
Use the following code.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class XsltTester extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = XsltTester.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {

            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.weather));
            Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.weatherxsl));

            TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
//          FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
//          fo.write(resizeBitMapImageToByteArray(photoAlbumBean));
//          fo.close();
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mydata.html");

//            OutputStream output = new StringOutputStream();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
            trans.transform(xmlSource, result);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: @Deepak : Thanks for the reply. This gives me the error "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". I used the same xsl and xml files used in the given link. Thanks

Comment: Download sample xml and xslt file from the url. but give separate name  and paste it in raw folder http://codingwithpassion.blogspot.com/2010/12/transform-xml-into-html-using-xslt.html

Comment: @Deepak : I used the exact code u gave and put the xml and xslt file in the raw folder.(I created the raw folder manually)
Now I don't get any errors, but no output as well.
What can I do?

Comment: your output is stored in a file you have to pull that file mydata.html in sd card. to see the output oull that file from the sdcard of your emulator

Comment: @Deepak : I'm having a little problem in finding the file, mydata.html. How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add:

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml` as this noob eventually found out :)

Comment: This should be included as a comment on the question.  While helpful, it doesn't answer the question.