# How to load a xml into a webview android

Tags: android, webview

I have an xml file and I want to load the xml content to a web view where the web view will be inflated to a gallery. I have parsed and able to get the parsed values, but how do I load the xml content to a web view?

This is the code I am using to load xml:

```
public class ReadContent extends Activity implements GalleryListener {
private GalleryView myGallery;
Context mContext = null;
private ContentAdapter contentAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.readcontent);
    myGallery = (GalleryView) findViewById(R.id.myGallery);
    myGallery.setGalleryListener(ReadContent.this);
    myGallery.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    contentAdapter = new ContentAdapter();
    myGallery.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
}

class ContentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Intro.book.getsecretList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // view = inflater.inflate(resourceid, null);
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.webviewitem, null);
        }
        synchronized (view) {
            TextView txtTopic = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtChapter);
            TextView txtSubTopic = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtSubChapter);
            WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.contentWebView);
            txtTopic.setText(Intro.book.getsecretList().get((int) position)
                    .getId().toString());
            txtSubTopic.setText(Intro.book.getsecretList()
                    .get((int) position).getId().toString());
            // webview content
            WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
            wv.setBackgroundColor(0);
            wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xxx.xml");
        }
        return view;
    }
}}
```

Help me with the code please, I would be grateful.

```
<prelim>
    <prelimTitle>Managing people is hard but rewarding</prelimTitle>
    <prelimIntro>As you go through life, you will increasingly find that you need to manage people. A parent has to manage their family; a supervisor or team leader has to manage a small team; an entrepreneur may have to manage staff, customers and suppliers.</prelimIntro>
    <prelimInsight>Knowing how to manage people well is one of the most important skills in life.</prelimInsight>
    <prelimContent>

        <![CDATA[
        <p>Early in my career I took responsibility for managing people. I managed up to 250 highly trained professionals who worked as a tight-knit team. It didn’t matter that I was the youngest person in the team! For over 20 years I’ve been working with individuals and organizations to help them improve their management of people. This has ranged from military personnel to entrepreneurs, from charities to government departments. I’ve learned many secrets and tricks over these years. Some I’ve discovered for myself, but many I’ve learned from others. Humans are wonderfully inventive!</p>
        <p>This book aims to help you improve your skills at managing people – to help you find ways in which everybody benefits. It contains 50 secrets, grouped into seven themed chapters.</p> 
        <p>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Build on a strong foundation.</span><span class='normalText'>You must understand what type of leader or manager you want to be. Your employer may give guidelines, but you must exert control over your day-to-day behaviour.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Create a great team.</span><span class='normalText'>This shows how to choose the right people and quickly build a functioning team.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Set goals and targets.</span><span class='normalText'>By setting people effective targets and goals, you can monitor progress and offer appropriate rewards.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Motivate yourself and your people.</span><span class='normalText'>Implementing ways to motivate people is ultimately much easier than having to cajole and constantly monitor unmotivated people.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Manage good performance.</span><span class='normalText'>You need to recognize good performance – reward it, develop it, perpetuate it and spread it to others.  Otherwise you will lose your good performers and be left only with the poor ones.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Manage poor performance.</span><span class='normalText'>Some managers find ways of managing around poor performance without tackling the poor performance itself. However, this encourages more poor performance, from both the original perpetrator and everyone else. Know how to tackle the problems head on.</span>   
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class='pointHeading'>Develop your people.</span><span class='normalText'>Though often overlooked by managers, another fundamental task is developing people. You need to improve the less able, stretch and reward the able, plan succession for the future and mentor your people’s changing needs. </span>   
        </li>
        </ul>
        </p>
        <p>Managing people is a hugely complex area in which you never stop learning. The secrets contained in this book will help you make massive strides towards succeeding in this fascinating role.</p>
        ]]>
    </prelimContent>
</prelim>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to show content in  tag,

then parse your xml, and display webview as:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, myPreviewContents, mime, encoding, null);
```

where `myPreviewContents` are:

```
<p>Early in my career I took responsibility for managing people. I managed up to 250 highly trained professionals who worked as a tight-knit team. It didn’t matter that I was the youngest person in the team! For over 20 years I’ve been working with individuals and organizations to help them improve their management of people. This has ranged from military personnel to entrepreneurs, from charities to government departments. I’ve learned many secrets and tricks over these years. Some I’ve discovered for myself, but many I’ve learned from others. Humans are wonderfully inventive!</p>
        <p>This book aims to help you improve your skills at managing people – to help you find ways in which everybody benefits. It contains 50 secrets, grouped into seven themed chapters.</p> 
    <p>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Build on a strong foundation.</span><span class='normalText'>You must understand what type of leader or manager you want to be. Your employer may give guidelines, but you must exert control over your day-to-day behaviour.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Create a great team.</span><span class='normalText'>This shows how to choose the right people and quickly build a functioning team.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Set goals and targets.</span><span class='normalText'>By setting people effective targets and goals, you can monitor progress and offer appropriate rewards.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Motivate yourself and your people.</span><span class='normalText'>Implementing ways to motivate people is ultimately much easier than having to cajole and constantly monitor unmotivated people.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Manage good performance.</span><span class='normalText'>You need to recognize good performance – reward it, develop it, perpetuate it and spread it to others.  Otherwise you will lose your good performers and be left only with the poor ones.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Manage poor performance.</span><span class='normalText'>Some managers find ways of managing around poor performance without tackling the poor performance itself. However, this encourages more poor performance, from both the original perpetrator and everyone else. Know how to tackle the problems head on.</span>   
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class='pointHeading'>Develop your people.</span><span class='normalText'>Though often overlooked by managers, another fundamental task is developing people. You need to improve the less able, stretch and reward the able, plan succession for the future and mentor your people’s changing needs. </span>   
    </li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p>Managing people is a hugely complex area in which you never stop learning. The secrets contained in this book will help you make massive strides towards succeeding in this fascinating role.</p>
    ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `xml` file is not always a webpage. You have to give a valid web page in `loadUrl()` like

```
  wv.loadUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk"");
```

Or use this is you have raw html :

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

(Yes, Android uses xml files for it's UI. It inflates Views using the xml as a skeleton )

Comment: how do i do that i only have xml not html..do i have to convert the xml into html

Comment: You'll have to show me what that XML contains. Remember that xml, by itself, can't be used to render a webpage. Only if your file can be rendered by a browser like Chrome or FireFox, will WebView be able to render it.

Comment: Reno i have added my xml pls see and help me pls

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsl to transform your xml, then load the resulting string into the webivew (webview.loaddata, I believe).

See [Android: Convert xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153560/android-convert-xml-using-xslt) for example transforming xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) android developer tutorial on XML parsing, download the sample code and modify it according to your XML file. It starts by parsing an XML, then it goes on creating an HTML code string and at the end it renders this HTML string in a simple webView.