# How to display xml file in webview Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to display an xml file stored in external storage in webview. But i am getting blank screen.

I tried this code:

```
xml.loadUrl(path_to_file);
```

Comment: Can i know the reason for down voting? Without giving a specific reason down voting is rude.;-(

Comment: look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928100/how-to-load-a-xml-into-a-webview-android

hope you help you

Comment: @Paul i tried it but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Trying loading your xml into a webview then displaying it from there